# remove backslash from json Result AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to remove all "\" from my Json result.

My Json result is :

```
 $scope.ContactList = [{"User":{"Country":{"CountryID":"US","CountryIDISO3":"USA","CountryOrder":999,"CountryName":"UNITED STATES","CountryISDCode":null,"ContinentCode":"NA","CreatedBy":"admin@gpsonline.com","CreatedOn":"2016-07-01T00:00:00","ModifiedBy":null,"ModifiedOn":null},"UserID":100001,"UserType":"US","UserEmail":"user@gp.com","UserPassword":"12345","UserPhone":"5587452036","FirstName":"Userupdate","LastName":"Testupdate","Address":"","Company":"","WorkPhone":"","Gender":"M","DateOfBirth":"1986-02-10T00:00:00","CountryID":"US","VerifiedPIN":null,"VerifiedEmail":"N","Signature":null,"isSignup":null,"PageCount":0,"CreatedBy":null,"CreatedOn":null,"ModifiedBy":null,"ModifiedOn":null},"UserContactUser":null,"UserContactID":3,"UserID":100001,"UserContactName":"Palash","UserContactPhone":"6520189650","UserContactEmail":"s@c.com","InviteSent":"N","InviteAccepted":"N","InviteAcceptedOn":null,"InviteRejected":"N","InviteRejectedOn":null,"InviteRemoved":"N","InviteRemovedOn":null,"UserContactUserID":0,"UserGroupList":"[{\"User\":{\"Country\":{\"CountryID\":\"US\",\"CountryIDISO3\":\"USA\",\"CountryOrder\":999,\"CountryName\":\"UNITED STATES\",\"CountryISDCode\":null,\"ContinentCode\":\"NA\",\"CreatedBy\":\"admin@gpsonline.com\",\"CreatedOn\":\"2016-07-01T00:00:00\",\"ModifiedBy\":null,\"ModifiedOn\":null},\"UserID\":100001.0,\"UserType\":\"US\",\"UserEmail\":\"user@gp.com\",\"UserPassword\":\"12345\",\"UserPhone\":\"5587452036\",\"FirstName\":\"Userupdate\",\"LastName\":\"Testupdate\",\"Address\":\"\",\"Company\":\"\",\"WorkPhone\":\"\",\"Gender\":\"M\",\"DateOfBirth\":\"1986-02-10T00:00:00\",\"CountryID\":\"US\",\"VerifiedPIN\":null,\"VerifiedEmail\":\"N\",\"Signature\":null,\"isSignup\":null,\"PageCount\":0,\"CreatedBy\":null,\"CreatedOn\":null,\"ModifiedBy\":null,\"ModifiedOn\":null},\"UserGroupID\":1.0,\"UserGroupOwnerID\":100001.0,\"UserGroupOwnerName\":null,\"UserGroupOwnerEmail\":null,\"UserGroupOwnerPhone\":null,\"UserGroupName\":\"test\",\"UserGroupDescription\":\"test\",\"UserGroupIcon\":null,\"UserGroupActive\":null,\"PageCount\":null}]
```

I already try with `JSON.stringify($scope.ContactList).replace(/\\/g, "")` option but replace it object is changed from json to string.
and `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.ContactList))` also but not working for me

could you give me any suggestion?

Comment: why are they there? would be the better/proper question. I'd say your backend messes up the response, and you should fix that rather than trying to parse the mess.

Comment: I get this json result from c# backend, now i want to remove all "\" by javascript or jquery

Comment: That's what I'm saying, the C# backend produces a malicious output. That's the real problem to fix.

Comment: is it possible to fix this by javascript or jquery?

Comment: yea, sure. But why do you insist on patching the malicious response, instead of fixing the bug?

Comment: because i need to do it form front end process @ [Thomas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6567275/thomas)